# How to get count for specific value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, count

I use following code:

```
$query = "SELECT ves, COUNT(ves) FROM books GROUP BY ves"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(ves)'] ." books";
echo "<br />";
}
```

I gives me following result:

There are 176 books.
There are 5 books.

First line result is total books on db.
I need to get only second result that correspond to the value for ves colum,  How can I get this?

Thank you in advance.
NPinelo

Comment: Above query could result in multiple resultset one per distinct ves column.

Answer (score 0):

Use a var (in this case `$i`) to control when you are in the second row

```
    $query = "SELECT ves, COUNT(ves) FROM books GROUP BY ves"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    // Print out result

$i = 1;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if($i == 2) {

    echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(ves)'] ." books";
    echo "<br />";

}

$i++;
    }
```

Comment: @user2752356 you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
$query = "SELECT ves, COUNT(ves) as ves_count FROM books GROUP BY ves"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "There are ". $row['ves_count'] ." books";
echo "<br />";
}
```

1. here at first you have to make an alias for getting counted values
2. and secondly use $row['ves_count'] instead of $row['COUNT(ves)']

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all helpfull minds, following code was what finally working as I need:

```
$query = "SELECT ven, COUNT(ven) FROM books WHERE ven='en'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "Here are ". $row['COUNT(ven)'] ." books";
echo "<br />";
}
```